# How do I check if a child is moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing a script in unity for an object which is held by the player and I need to check if it is moving. (3d)

```
        if(transform.hasChanged)
        {
            Debug.Log("not Moved");
            isMoving = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Moved");
            isMoving = true;
        }
```

Once the object is picked up it is attached to the parent, which is the player, and when the player moves their camera or moves with the keys the held object moves with them, however its transform remains the same because it is relative to the parent.

Id like to know if there is a way to check the objects global position or something else to indicates if the object is moving.

Also I have tried checking if the position has changed each update by comparing it to the last, but this way is highly inconsistent so it flickers the "isMoving" bool between false and true and the script requires it to be precise and consistent.

Comment: `(Transform).position` is the world position.  `(Transform).localPosition` is the position relative to the parent.  You should wait some amount of time before setting the moving bool, a handful of frames should be sufficient.  ie.  if you detect its no longer moving, start counting frames until you reach the count, resetting frame counter if it moved.  If you reach the count then set the bool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would stick to the simple check of

```
private Vector3 lastPosition;

private void Update()
{
    var currentPosition = transform.position;
    isMoving = currentPosition != lastPosition;
    lastPosition = currentPosition;
}
```

> the script requires it to be precise and consistent.

Is actually contradicting. The upper being **precise** - meaning `isMoving` actually reflects the current state - seems to be exactly not what you want.

=> You rather want to add some sort of imprecision in order to "stabelize" it out.

---

It depends a bit on your needs and whether false-positives or false-negatives are worse for your use case. Your description sounds like you are mainly concerned about false-negatives meaning the `isMoving` should stay enabled for a bit even if the object is not moved for a split second.

You could use a simple timer for that and do something like

```
[SerializeField] float stopMovingDelay = 0.5f;

private Vector3 lastPosition;
private float timer;    

private void Update()
{
    var currentPosition = transform.position;
    var moving = currentPosition != lastPosition;
    lastPosition = currentPosition;

    if(moving)
    {
        timer = 0;
        IsMoving = true;
    } 
    else if(timer < stopMovingDelay)
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        if(timer >= stopMovingDelay)
        {
            IsMoving = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally you could also reduce the precision of the position check so the object also only enters the `IsMoving` state if moved far enough like e.g.

```
[SerializeField] float movingPrecision = 0.01;
[SerializeField] float stopMovingDelay = 0.5f;

private Vector3 lastPosition;
private float timer;    

private void Update()
{
    var currentPosition = transform.position;
    var moving = (currentPosition - lastPosition).sqrMagnitude > movingPrecision * movingPrecision;
    
    if(moving)
    {
        timer = 0;
        IsMoving = true;
        lastPosition = currentPosition;
    } 
    else if(timer < stopMovingDelay)
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        if(timer >= stopMovingDelay)
        {
            IsMoving = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This way, the object e.g. has to be moved at least `0.01` units from the previous stored position in order to count as moving. You might introduce some more false-negatives again if the user is moving the object really slow - so you will have to play around with the parameters and see what works best for you. You could even adjust both dynamically depending on the distance the object is moved each frame, add prediction etc but this should do for now ;)